# TIMES_ROMAN Font not found in PDFBox Java Library

Tags: java, fonts, pdfbox

I am trying to write text into PDF using PDFBox in java. But when I want to set the font, it is not available. I looked at some tutorials and there is no difference with my code. What is wrong?

Here is the error:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable TIMES_ROMAN
  location: class org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font
```

Here is the code:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentInformation;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import java.io.IOException;

public class app {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        for(int x=0;x<10;x++){
            PDPage myPage = new PDPage();
            document.addPage(myPage);
        }

        PDPage page = document.getPage(1);
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document,page);
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 12);

        document.save("C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/testPDFBOX.pdf");
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use version 2.0.29 ? Or a 3.0 version?

Comment: Don't forget to close `contentStream` and call `endText()`. And to actually output some text. (Unrelated to your problem, but this is the next problem you'll get)

Comment: And `document.getPage(1)` means you're writing to the second page, because it's 0 based.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue might be because the static font instances were removed in pdfbox 3.

I hit this issue with pdfbox 3.0.0 whilst trying to follow a tutorial for pdfbox 2.0.8.

In the [pdfbox 3 migration notes](https://pdfbox.apache.org/3.0/migration.html) I found this:

> The static instances of PDType1Font for the standard 14 fonts were removed as the underlying COSDictionary isn't supposed to be immutable which led to several issues.
>
> A new constructor for PDType1Font was introduced to create a standard 14 font. The new Enum Standard14Fonts.FontName is the one and only parameter and defines the name of the standard 14 font for which the instance of PDType1Font is created for. That instance isn't a singleton anymore and has to be recreated if necessary or cached by the user if suitable.

Translating to code, this is how you access fonts:

```java
// 2.0.8
PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN

// 3.0.0
new PDType1Font(Standard14Fonts.FontName.TIMES_ROMAN)
```

In the broader context of your code sample, this would set the font for 3.0.0:

```java
contentStream.setFont(new PDType1Font(Standard14Fonts.FontName.TIMES_ROMAN), 12);
```

and you'll need an additional import:

```java
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.Standard14Fonts;
```

This got me past my compiler issue I was able to render and save a pdf successfully.

The full 14 standard font names are all loaded [here](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/Standard14Fonts.java#L71) and there's some other mappings below.

See also the comments below your post about cleaning up resources.

Hope that helps. Disclaimer: I'm completely new to pdfbox.