# PDFBox prints giant error and takes very long to create PDF

Tags: java, pdfbox

Im trying to create an PDF in java and I am pretty much ready, but when I try to start the program the compiler an extreme long error message and it takes about 30 seconds until the pdf is created.

```
public void CreatePDF(){
        try {
            // Erstellen Sie ein neues Dokument und fügen Sie eine Seite hinzu
            
            
            PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            document.addPage(page);

            // Öffnen Sie den Dateiauswahldialog
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Speichern Sie die PDF-Datei");

            // Zeigen Sie den Dialog an und warten Sie auf die Auswahl des Benutzers
            int userSelection = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);

            if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                // Der Benutzer hat einen Speicherort ausgewählt
                File fileToSave = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

                // Erstellen Sie den Inhalt des PDF-Dokuments
                PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
                contentStream.setFont(new PDType1Font(Standard14Fonts.FontName.HELVETICA), 12);

                // Überschrift
                contentStream.beginText();
                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(100, 750);
                contentStream.showText("Überschrift");
                contentStream.endText();

                // Text unter der Überschrift
                contentStream.beginText();
                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(100, 730);
                contentStream.showText("Mein eigenes Variable: Wert");
                contentStream.endText();

                contentStream.close();

                // Speichern Sie das PDF-Dokument am ausgewählten Speicherort
                document.save(fileToSave);
                document.close();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Speichern abgebrochen.");
            }
        }  catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("IOException aufgetreten:");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I tried the tips from here: [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76710623/times-roman-font-not-found-in-pdfbox-java-library)

Comment: What version are you using? In 3.0.* there are a lot of (harmless) errors messages when the font cache is created the first time. Sondern bugs were fixed in 3.0.1 and later in the current snapshot.

Comment: If the *compiler* shows a long *error* message, the program shouldn't start at all... what exactly do you observe?